# How to get maximum no of id exist in one table?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I want to find the maximum number of `id`s present in a table. For example, I have a `user_views` table:

```
      user_views
 -------------------
 u_v_id   package_id 
   1            24
   2            24
   3            24
   4            25
   5            25
   6            26
   7            27
```

And a packages table:

```
 package_id      name
```

The maximum number of `id`s which are present in one table is 24 and so on.

How can I write a query to pull that value?

Comment: the desired out put will be 24

Comment: You really need to clarify a little bit.

Comment: I want package name from packages table who have most package_id present or exist in user_views table.

Comment: So if I am understanding correctly `u_v_id` is the primary key of `user_views` and `package_id` is the foreign key to the packages table.

Comment: basically the problem is that I m not getting success with join.

Answer (score 3):

```
select package_id, count(*) as Count
from MyTable
group by package_id
order by count(*) desc
limit 1
```

Comment: join is not working with this query    select package_id, count(*) as Count
from user_views inner JOIN packages on packages.package_id = user_views.package_id
group by package_id
order by count(*) desc

Comment: i tried your query because it is simple compared with @JW but the problem is it does not handle duplicates right? see here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/edae1/4

Answer (score 1):

The query below will support duplicate `package_ID` for having the maximum number of views.

```
SELECT  package_ID
FROM    user_views
GROUP   BY package_ID
HAVING  COUNT(*) = 
(
    SELECT  COUNT(*) totalCount
    FROM    user_views
    GROUP   BY package_ID
    ORDER   BY totalCount DESC
    LIMIT   1
)
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/68233/1)
- [SQLFiddle Demo (*with duplicate record having the most views*)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/edae1/1)

Comment: JW and @ RedFilter if I want to join with packages table then what I do?

Comment: join it on the outer statement and change `COUNT(*)` into `COUNT(distinct u_v_id)`.

Comment: can you give me sample of table you want to join and their relationship?

Comment: I want package name from packages table who have most package_id present or exist in user_views table.

Comment: you have a syntax error on your query. it's not `COUNT()` but instead `COUNT(*)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the maximum number in a database, use `MAX()`:

```
SELECT
    MAX(`column`) as `max`
FROM
    `table`
```

or if you want to find the amount of unique ID's in a database, use `COUNT()`:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT `column`) as `count`
FROM
    `table`
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the `package_id` value then use CodeIgniter's built in Active Record class:

```
$this->db->select('user_views.u_v_id', 'packages.package_id', 'packages.name');
$this->db->from('user_views');
$this->db->join('packages', 'user_views.package_id=packages.package_id');
$query = $this->db->get();
```